# How to import AppDelegate.h from another Framework in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I have a framework called "MyFramework.xcodeproj" that is added to my main project. Within this framework, I'm working on a file that needs a reference to my AppDelegate.h file. It isn't able to locate it, and when I try to add the file from "Build Phases" in "Compile Sources" it isn't able to find it there either. How can I get the reference to this file?

Answer (score 0):

Your framework should ideally be separate from any application delegate logic. However, if you *do* need access to it, you can simply cast the shared application delegate to `AppDelegate`.

```
(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Just copy `AppDelegate`'s `@interface` and put it somewhere visible in your framework. `AppDelegate.m` does not need to be there.

Comment: Would I just add @interface AppDelegate.h into my current class?